# Тонкости preg_match в PHP

Tags: php

Может ли $matches быть ассоциативным массивом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Он может быть смешанным. Вот пример:

```
<?php

$str = '2016-10-06';
if (preg_match('%^(?P<year>\d+)-(?P<month>\d+)-(?P<day>\d+)$%', $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Результат:

```
array (size=7)
  0 => string '2016-10-06' (length=10)
  'year' => string '2016' (length=4)
  1 => string '2016' (length=4)
  'month' => string '10' (length=2)
  2 => string '10' (length=2)
  'day' => string '06' (length=2)
  3 => string '06' (length=2)
```

Comment: Да, я тоже про это вычитал, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Массив `$matches` содержит все вхождения найденных подстрок. А индекс в массиве - индекс подстроки в регулярном выражении